# MySqlClient Table doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio

I have problem with my program. When I'm using localhost server, no error. But when I'm migration to public server I got some error.

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException'
>   occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Table 'mydatabase.Users' doesn't exist

My code :

```
MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection
MySqlConnection.ConnectionString = "server=mypublicip;port=3306;user id=root;password=password; database=mydatabase"
MySqlConnection.Open()

frmScan.LogList.Text = frmScan.LogList.Text & frmScan.txtTime.Text & "  | Mencoba mengabsen " & vbNewLine

Dim MyAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim sqlquery = "SELECT * From Users WHERE Username='" & txtUser.Text & "'AND Password='" & txtPass.Text & "';"

Dim command As New MySqlCommand
command.Connection = MySqlConnection
command.CommandText = sqlquery

MyAdapter.SelectCommand = command
Dim Mydata As MySqlDataReader
Mydata = command.ExecuteReader
```

Thanks!

Comment: the localhost in windows based and public server is a linux/unix server  ????

Comment: Probably someone has already logged in with "  ';drop table users;--    "as a password

Comment: @scaisEdge yes localhost based on windows, and public server based on ubuntu server.

Comment: This will crazy vulnerable to sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If localhost in windows based and public server is a linux/unix server based .. then:

First check if the table User exists on server.

But check ttaht the tablename  called in your query and the file table name for the related  mySql table data container is exactly the same.

Because windows  filename are not case sensitive but unix like filenames  are case sentive .. 
the if you use

```
Select * From User
```

check on your server for table `User` and not `user` of others case sequence

Or adapt your tablename in query to your filename on server